# Linux network interface management by C code

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, posix

I am looking for a function/system call that can be used in C to manage network interfaces of the Linux machine. E.g.,  I would like to do `ip link set wlan0 down`(or up) or `ifconfig wlan0 down`, what function can be used for it, apart from `system()`?

Comment: A good starting point might be looking at how ifconfig itself does it - you can find the source code here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/net-tools/

Comment: Also, [DBUS NetworkManager API](http://projects.gnome.org/NetworkManager/developers/api/09/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access the functionality provided by the iproute2 tools from software, you can use the [Linux rtnetlink API](http://linux.die.net/man/7/rtnetlink). To make it easier for you, use libraries like [libnl](http://www.carisma.slowglass.com/~tgr/libnl/).

In case you encounter trouble, there is already a tag called [netlink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netlink)

Comment: The link for libnl is out of date. I think this is the right place now: https://github.com/thom311/libnl

Answer (score -3):

Use a system call to execute a command like you would on the command line.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

int system(const char *command);

[man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system)

Comment: I believe @angs explicitly said he needed something different from system() ;)